# How to handle delete popup confirmation for an api in reactjs

Tags: reactjs, react-redux, popup, delete-operator, react-modal

Could anyone help me out here please, all I'm trying to do here  is to show popup modal confirmation for  delete action, but every time I clicked on **Yes **btn to confirm  my delete action the last product on the list always get deleted instead. I need help from anyone please?

Here is my code for handling the delete popup

````
    ```
     //OPEN DELETE MODALS
      const [openDeleteModal, isOpenDeleteModal] = useState(false);
      const closeDeleteModal = () => {
        isOpenDeleteModal(false);
        document.body.style.overflow = "unset";
      };
      const showDeleteModal = () => {
        isOpenDeleteModal(true);
      };
    ```
````

and here is the api

````
    ```
    //DELETE PRODUCT
      const deleteHandler = async (product) => {
        try {
          await axios.delete(`/api/products/${product._id}`, {
            headers: { Authorization: `Bearer ${userInfo.token}` },
          });
          toast.success("product deleted successfully", {
            position: "bottom-center",
          });
          dispatch({ type: "DELETE_SUCCESS" });
        } catch (err) {
          toast.error(getError(err), { position: "bottom-center" });
          dispatch({ type: "DELETE_FAIL" });
        }
      };
    ```
````

down here is my modal for confirmation

````
    ```
     {/* MODAL */}
                                  {openDeleteModal && (
                                    <div className="delete-modal">
                                      <div className="delete-modal-box">
                                        <div className="delete-modal-content">
                                          <p className="delete-modal-content-p">
                                            Are you sure to delete this product?
                                          </p>
                                          <div className="delete-modal-btn">
                                            <button
                                              onClick={closeDeleteModal}
                                              className="delete-modal-btn-close"
                                            >
                                              Close
                                            </button>
                                            <button
                                              onClick={() => {
                                                deleteHandler(product);
                                                closeDeleteModal();
                                              }}
                                              className="delete-modal-btn-yes"
                                            >
                                              {" "}
                                              Yes
                                            </button>
                                          </div>
                                        </div>
                                      </div>
                                    </div>
                                  )}
    ```
    



All I'm trying to do is to be able to delete any product from the list not the last product every time.
````

**here is the entirety of my productList map looks like**

```
 {products?.map((product, index) => (
                        <tr className="product-item-list" key={index}>
                          <tr>
                            <td className="product-item-id">{product._id}</td>
                            <td className="product-item-name">
                              {product.name}
                            </td>
                            <td className="product-item-price">
                              £{product.price}
                            </td>
                            <td className="product-item-category">
                              {product.category?.map((cat, index) => (
                                <span key={index}>{cat}</span>
                              ))}
                            </td>

                            <td className="product-item-size">
                              {product.size?.map((s, index) => (
                                <span key={index}>{s}&nbsp;</span>
                              ))}
                            </td>
                            <td className="product-btn-view">
                              <button
                                className="product-btn"
                                onClick={() =>
                                  navigate(`/admin/productedit/${product._id}`)
                                }
                              >
                                Edit
                              </button>
                              &nbsp;
                              <DeleteOutline
                                className="product-delete"
                                onClick={showDeleteModal}
                              />
                              {/* MODAL */}
                              {openDeleteModal && (
                                <div className="delete-modal">
                                  <div className="delete-modal-box">
                                    <div className="delete-modal-content">
                                      <p className="delete-modal-content-p">
                                        Are you sure to delete this product?
                                      </p>
                                      <div className="delete-modal-btn">
                                        <button
                                          onClick={closeDeleteModal}
                                          className="delete-modal-btn-close"
                                        >
                                          Close
                                        </button>
                                        <button
                                          onClick={() => {
                                            deleteHandler(product);
                                            closeDeleteModal();
                                          }}
                                          className="delete-modal-btn-yes"
                                        >
                                          {" "}
                                          Yes
                                        </button>
                                      </div>
                                    </div>
                                  </div>
                                </div>
                              )}
                            </td>
                          </tr>
                          <tr></tr>
                        </tr>
                      ))}
```

Answer (score 0):

I guess it happens because all of your modals open when you call `showDeleteModal`
And the last one is on the top, so when you click to delete the last closure works. Maybe its nessesary to pass id of product into the `openDeleteModal`. And than check if product.id equals to `openDeleteModal`.

Answer (score 0):

Can you print to console the product.id when you click on the "Delete" button and check is it the correct id of the clicked product?